# Updating one itemView within a recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have one activity with just one recyclerview within -
This is what one of my activity looks like:

[image: activity]

Inside my recyclerview, there are two types of views. One is the profile view, which shows my name, age and gender and the other is the information view, which gives information on the courses I have subscribed to. I decided to sit both views in the recyclerview so that both views will scroll up when the user scrolls this recyclerview.

To create this, I did the following:

```
public class FeedRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Info> info;
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return PROFILE;
            case 1:
                return INFO;
        }
    }

        public ProfileFeedActivityRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Info> info) {
            this.info = info;
        }

  @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case PROFILE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_profile_info, parent, false);
                return new ProfileInfoViewHolder(view);
            case INFO:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_information, parent, false);
                return new InformationViewHolder(view);
            }
        }

class ProfileInfoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView profilePic;
        TextView name;
        TextView age;
        TextView gender;
        public ProfileInfoViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            //get a handler on all these textviews / imageViews and set the text or image based on whatever is stored in sharedPrefs.
           }
    }

class InformationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView heading;
        TextView subheading;
         public InformationViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            //get a handler on these views so that I can bind them in the onBindViewHolder method
            }
        }

         @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if (holder instanceof ProfileInfoViewHolder) {
            //do nothing as everything was pulled from sharedPrefs. There is no object to back this view.
        }
        if (holder instanceof InformationViewHolder) {
            ((InformationViewHolder)holder).heading.setText(info.get(position).getHeading());
            //binding the view to the arrayList that was passed into the adapter.
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let say I can change my privacy settings to show/hide my age in the profile itemView. I easily change it the boolean within my sharedPreference file to reflect the age as `false` but I want to update my recyclerview so that it hides my age immediately when I change the setting so what I did was `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter so that the recyclerview updates itself.

Since the profile itemView was not backed by any objects, all its data was pulled from sharedPreferences and it was not sitting within the `ArrayList info`, the dataset which is my `ArrayList info` was never changed hence `notifyDataSetChanged()` has no effect.

How do get the profile itemView to update itself when a setting has been changed?

Comment: How do you update the arraylist info?

Comment: You can see that the arraylist info is passed into the adapter using the constructor for the adapter. The views are created in the method getItemViewType but that is based on the position of the item in the recyclerview, so if it is the first item, we would display the profile view. It is not based on the arraylist of object like how a normal adapter is based. In a normal adapter, you would base the recyclerview views on the arraylist of objects. In my adapter, you are basing it on the position of objects in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener to get notifies if some key has been changed and to notify your ui.

You'll get the Preference object and the new value.

[Check this for more information](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html)

Comment: I could also use a listener in an interface but I dont think it would work because you are not changing the view in a normal layout. You are changing an itemView in an adapter, and as far as I know, you cannot get a handler on an ItemView in the adapter.

Comment: Change the DATA OBJECT in the array you're providing the adapter to. and then notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I feared that I would have to do that. Its just annoying because now I would have to add in empty fields for each data object for name, gender and age when I'm only using those fields for my first ItemView and not all the other views.

Comment: You have to. keep your data always in front of ui. your first item must be update throw bindView/getView so keep reference to your data object which will be get updates from some other place, then it would be very simple.